# socketio.emit() not making it to the user when called from monkey patched gevent thread

Tags: python, flask-socketio

I have code that can send messages up to a connected user with `socketio.emit()`, but when doing the same thing from a gevent thread, the data never makes it to the client.

Sample code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, join_room, leave_room, emit
import gevent
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '<redacted>'
app.debug = False
socket = SocketIO(app, async_mode="gevent")

def sendStamina(sessionId, stamina):
    # have to use socket.emit here, simply because this function is called from an BG thread.
    with app.test_request_context('/'):
        socket.emit('stamina', {'sessiondId': sessionId, 'stamina': stamina}, room=sessionId)
        print("sent satmina update")

def stamina_update():
    print("stamina update called")
    next_call = time.time()
    while 1:
        print("stamina update called inside")
        next_call = next_call + 1
        gevent.sleep(next_call - time.time())
        sendStamina(<data>, <data>)


t1 = gevent.spawn(game.stamina_update)
t2 = gevent.spawn(start_server)
gevent.joinall([t1, t2])
```

I've seen a few threads about this on SO and socketio's forums, and it's gotten me closer, but I'm still missing something...

Comment: There are important things that you have not included in your example code. The `start_server` function, how do you connect on the client and the client side event handler for the "stamina" event. Running the server with verbose logging enabled and a log snippet that shows both working and non-working emits would also be useful to figure this out.

Comment: Calling `stamina_update()` from the main thread `start_server()` thread works just fine. Calling `stamina_update()` from any other thread results in no data being sent.

Also, I'll update the code above to give more detail.